# Response from Web Server is dependent on ZeroMQ (0MQ) RES

Tags: web-services, soa, zeromq

In lightweight SOAs I've seen many designs that have a Web Server receives Client requests and send responses that are dependent upon responses from other services.  I've also seen this done incorrectly resulting in unacceptable latency issues.

For Example:

> Assume:
>
> - We have 1 Web API Server and 1 Service A API.
> - Web Server performs basic User Auth and other User functionality.
> - Service A performs database operations.
> - ZeroMQ (ZMQ, 0MQ, etc) REQ/RES user for service messaging
>
> Work Flow:
>
> 1. Client makes request to Web API Server API.
> 2. Web Server performs database operations (auth etc).
> 3. Web Server makes request to Service A API.
> 4. Service A performs database operations.
> 5. Service A responds with data to Web Server.
> 6. Web Server receives response and sends response to client.

This pattern is different from the typical offline message queue processing work flow.  As well it includes a request to a single service (A)

While trying to maintain separate system services is this a correct usage pattern with ZeroMQ?

I'm trying to figure out if ZeroMQ can be used to make service requests and send the results to client web service requests without significant performance issues.